# How to cancel label highlighting in WebStorm？

Tags: webstorm

This color is too light,how to change or remove the color?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using custom color scheme -- it's hard to guess what style is causing this if I do not have such scheme myself.

But so far it looks like "Matched Brace".

If I'm right:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Colors & Fonts`
3. `General | Code --> Matched brace`
4. Change color for "Background".

Comment: Yes,you are right.Please ask my another question like it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43652862/how-to-remove-brackets-highlighting-in-webstorm