# How to remove brackets highlighting in WebStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

This color cover the brackets. I don't want this.

How to remove the setting?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a image of the settings?I can't find what you said.

Comment: Post your settings (colors & fonts) for the matching brace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from `Editor`>`Color Scheme`>`General` in your IDE Settings. The setting you are looking for is under *Code* and is called **Matched Brace**.

On the right you should see a couple different settings which will allow you to control the way the matched braces look. For example, to remove the lime green border you can uncheck the **Effects** checkbox.

In your case, I believe it's likely that you have the **Foreground** checkbox set and that the color is configured to match your background color.

I'd suggest playing around with the **Matched Brace** color settings until you find a style you like. Unfortunately, the preview shown in this section doesn't give you a good example of a matched brace will look like. So you'll have to **Apply** the setting, look at your code, and re-edit if you want to make changes.

[image: Matched Brace Settings Examples]